# HTTPClient Post Returns Bad Request 400

Tags: c#, http

I've hit a brick wall. Please help. I never hit any breakpoints in my svc file so I don't know whats happening.

I've tried several other's solutions but no dice ....

my jsonstring is

```
string jsonString = "[{\"details\":\"Hello World\"}]";
```

Rest files .cs:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "updateDataViaPost", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        ResponseData updateDataViaPost(RequestData rdata);
```

Client Code:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var request = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, request).Result;
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

RequestData

```
public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string details { get; set; }
    }
```

It now makes it to the function here but rdata which is passed to it is null:

```
public Stream updateDataViaPost(RequestData rdata)
{
            
     var data = rdata.details.Split('|');

    ......
```

Looks like the string needed to be string jsonString = "[{"details":"Hello World"}]";

Comment: What is the value of `jsonString`? What is the structure of `RequestData`?

Comment: what's the uri you're sending your request to?

Comment: JSONSTING is hardcoded as "[{\"MealTypeID\":1}]"
Added Request Data above.
URI is: http://localhost:60621/RestServiceImpl.svc/updateDataViaPost once it is working would be pushed to the remote server

Comment: Can you share the hardcoded value of json string? Do you receive any content in the response along with 400 error? Can you share that too?

Comment: made some additions / changes above. Thanks everyone!!! It now gets stopped in the svc fuctnion updateDataViaPost(Reqeust Data rdata). rdata is null

Comment: have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715743/wcf-webinvoke-method-post

Comment: I recommend using a software like Postman to first verify that the API works with correct data, and then compare the raw JSON data with the data you use in postman. and you can simplify the code by new { variableName = variable value } and parse the object to json. let the code create the correct string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help!!!!!!!! Greatly appreciated.

For future reference for all this works now:

```
[DataContract]
    public class UpdateTableData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ColumnNames { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Values { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string WhereColumnNames { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string WhereValues { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public string updateDataViaPost(UpdateTableData rdata)
 {
           ..... (MY UNIQUE CODE)......
}
```

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "updateDataViaPost", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

        //ResponseData updateDataViaPost(RequestData rdata);
        string updateDataViaPost(UpdateTableData data);
```

```
string jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(updateTable);
```

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //POST Request

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var request = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                
                var response = client.PostAsync(URI, request).Result;
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                string strresult = result;
            }
```